# Close a Window thats in the background

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a school project right now, the main task is to create a simple Tic-Tac-Toe application in WinForms.

If you won the game a little animation pops up, saying that "Player XY" won. Normally the user would click the window away, but I would like to close it, even after the player let it open and clicked on "New Game".

That's where my problem comes in: If you're not clicking the window away and click on "New Game" on another window, the animation, which is now open, but behind the game field won't close.

This is some of the code for the "New Game" button:

```
private void New_Game_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Winscreen winscreenClose = new Winscreen();
    winscreenClose.CloseWinscreen();
}
```

this is the code inside `Winscreen`:

```
public void CloseWinscreen()
{
    this.Hide();
}
```

So the function gets called, but it doesn't close the Window. I also tried `this.Close();` and `Environment.Exit(0);` just to check that the function gets called properly, and it does.

Comment: you are creating a new instance and then immediately closing it.  to close the existing winscreen, you need to use the instance object you created to show it.

Answer (score 2):

You need a field in your main form:

```
private Winscreen winscreen = null;
```

When you're presenting the window to the user, assign the instance to this variable:

```
this.winscreen = new Winscreen();
this.winscreen.Show();    // or whatever you're doing currently
```

This way, you are able to store a *reference* to the window that is actually shown on the screen. In your current solution, you are creating a new instance each time - each of them having nothing to do with the previously opened window.

Then when starting a new game you can close the popup:

```
private void New_Game_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.winscreen != null)
    {
        this.winscreen.CloseWinscreen();
        this.winscreen = null;
    }

// ...
}
```

As [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) points out in the comments section below, you should also handle the case when the user will close the window by themselves. That's easy using an event handler. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: You should also provide an event handler for the closing event on the Winscreen form in case the user closes the form correctly instead of clicking the new game button. The evil is in the details ....